# MySQL multiple LIKE condition not working

Tags: mysql

I have following `query`.

```
SELECT seller_id, name, email, FROM login, seller
WHERE login.login_id = seller.login_id
AND
    seller.name LIKE '%$search%' AND login.email LIKE '%$search%'
```

My query result satisfies only first `LIKE` condition (`seller.name LIKE '%$search%'`), and doesn't satisfies second `LIKE` condition (`login.email LIKE '%$search%'`)

**For Example**
If `$search = "j"`, then it returns only one row that is,

```
seller_id | name  | email        
--------------------------------
 1        | jay   | jd@gmail.com
```

But I have second condition too that is `login.email LIKE '%$search%'` So for this example my desired result would be:

```
seller_id | name  | email        
---------------------------------
 1        | jay   | jd@gmail.com
 4        | vsm   | jay@gmail.com
```

I have following **Tables**.

**Table: Login**

```
login_id | email             | password
---------------------------------------
 4       | jd@gmail.com      | 123
 5       | fluttr@gmail.com  | 123
 6       | amy@gmail.com     | 123
 7       | jay@gmail.com     | 123
```

**Table: Seller**

```
seller_id | login_id | name  
-----------------------------
 1        | 4        | jay
 2        | 5        | rajesh
 3        | 6        | ema
 4        | 7        | vsm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line

```
seller.name LIKE '%$search%' AND login.email LIKE '%$search%'
```

`AND` will only return results that match *both* conditions at the same time, you want an `OR` instead:

```
SELECT seller_id, name, email, FROM login, seller
WHERE login.login_id = seller.login_id
AND 
     (seller.name LIKE '%$search%' OR login.email LIKE '%$search%')
```